# c to PowerShell equivalent operators conversion

Tags: powershell

in c i do

x &= ~1

I need to do this in powershell? have tried most things reviewed the powershell reference etc.

thanks

Comment: See Powershell bitwise operators -bnot -band

Comment: See here: http://bit.ly/15zGK2n

Comment: yes if tried it and cannot work it out $a = 98
$c = ($a -and (-not 1))
$c



$a = 98
$a = ($a -

Comment: @capsch `-band` `-bnot` note the `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent of the `&=` operator in PowerShell. The Powershell equivalent would be:

```
$x = $x -band (-bnot 1)
```